# Randomize в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Использовал Randomize (слышал что исключает повторение), для случайной последовательности от 1 до 10, но мне интересно, что выведет v:=1+Random(9); когда случайности кончаться? чему будет равен v?
Объясните пожалуйста доступным языком для начинающего.

Answer (score 4):

Принцип большинства алгоритмов получения случайных чисел - новое псевдослучайное значение получается на основе предыдущего значения.

Например, самое простенькое для С:

```
unsigned long rtrand( void ) {
  rtseed = rtseed * 0x41C64E6D + 0x3039; // получить новое значение случайное
  return (rtseed>>16)&0x7FFF; // обрезать его до нужной величины.
}
```

И, если программа будет начинаться с одним и тем же начальным значением, то вся цепочка повторится. Сколько угодно раз. Попробуйте посмотреть значения, создаваемые рандомом без этой функции.

```
Первый запуск программы: 1 9 8 5 7 3 2 9 4 8 (написал наугад)
Второй запуск программы: 1 9 8 5 7 3 2 9 4 8
Третий запуск программы: 1 9 8 5 7 3 2 9 4 8
...
```

А функция Randomize в качестве начального значения берёт какое-то число, которое всегда разное. Например, время в миллисекундах. Как бы не запускали программу, время уже не повторится.

И все цепочки станут другими.

```
Первый запуск программы: 3 9 1 7 4 9 2 3 8 2 (написал наугад)
Второй запуск программы: 1 5 6 3 3 4 6 7 2 9
Третий запуск программы: 3 4 8 2 5 1 6 8 3 1
...
```

Вряд ли вы встретите повторение цепочки при последовательном запросе чисел =) Цепочки там ужасть какие длинные)
Не думайте, что ограничивая выходной диапазон, вы заставите его повторяться - ограничение идёт на выходе алгоритма (обычно как остаток от деления **return (minval + rtseed mod (maxval - minval))**, внутри используются очень большие числа.

И да, не путайте повторение числа - а они будут повторяться, если их немного, - от повторения последовательности псевдослучайных чисел. Самое главное, чтобы эти числа укладывались в заданное случайное распределение =) Что, в принципе, задано алгоритмически и будет выполняться всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Функции randomize() и random() путать не надо.

1. randomize() - инициализирует ГСЧ определенным значением. Обычно это время. Дело в том, что ГСЧ с одним и тем же значением инициализации будет генерировать одинаковые последовательности чисел, т.к. он работает по строго определенному алгоритму.
2. random() - собственно ф-ция, которая получает из ГСЧ следующее число.

Чтобы понять разницу просто соберите программу с вызовом randomize() и без. И сравните последовательности из пяти-десяти случайных чисел. Ах, да, программу желательно запустить несколько раз в каждом из вариантов для обеспечения полной наглядности. Результат будет таков, что без randomize() последовательности будут одинаковы!!!

> v:=1+Random(9);

Выведет случайное число в диапазоне от 1+0 до 1+8, т.е. от 1 до 9.

> Когда случайности кончаться?

Будет цикл. :-) Т.е. начиная с какого момента числа начнут повторяться. Правда, для стандартного ГСЧ величина цикла весьма большая и на практике можно считать, что числа практически случайные.

Comment: А как выловить момент, когда числа начинают повторятся?
Ну т.е. все 10 чисел случайно вышли, и тут надо закончить программу?
Слышал что такое решение можно сделать списками, но в списках ограничение 255, а мне нужно больше. Поэтому хотелось бы ограничится Randomize, выловить конец всех псевдослучайностей и завершить программу.

Comment: <i>А как выловить момент, когда числа начинают повторятся?</i>
Поверьте - этот момент настанет через 10000+ вызовов. Придется сохранять все члены последовательности и искать среди них повторяющуюся подпоследовательность. 
<i>но в списках ограничение 255, а мне нужно больше.</i>
М-м-м.. Списки ничем не ограничены, кроме объема ОЗУ. Или о чем именно Вы говорите?
<i>Ну т.е. все 10 чисел случайно вышли</i>
Вы кажется не понимаете что значит 'случайное число из диапазона от A до B'. И что значит последовательность случайных чисел.

Comment: Если вы хотите получить конкретные числа в произвольном порядке, то так и ставьте вопрос - вам ответят именно на него =)

Answer (score 1):

Поясняю:

randomize - инициализатор генератора случайных чисел
random - без инициализации сгенерирует только одно случайное значение, при повторном вызове оно вернет то же число

обычно randomize включают в самом начале программы, можно еще поместить в OnCreate основной формы.

Comment: <i>без инициализации сгенерирует только одно случайное значение, при повторном вызове оно вернет то же число</i>
!?!?!? Ничего не понял. Можете формулировать чуть пояснее?

Comment: попытаюсь еще яснее... без рандомайз любой вызов рандом будет возвращать например 4, при вызове рандомайза перед рандомами будут возвращаться разные значения например 2 9 3 7

Comment: Неверно. Например, рандом без рандомайза выдает последовательность = 68 32 17 38 43 (вызвали random 5 раз за сеанс работы программы). При следующем запуске программы получим ту же самую последовательность. Но это совершенно неэквивалентно утверждению, что будет возвращаться, например, 4 4 4 4 4.

Comment: А какой тогда смысл в двух отдельных функциях, если каждый раз надо их две вызывать подряд?)

Comment: 2gecube, я не знаю откуда вы почерпнули насчет одинаковой цепочки, но я про одинаковые значения почерпнул из практики. Вполне может быть дело в компиляторе, но у меня получалось именно так.

2Алексей Сонькин, их не надо каждый раз подряд вызывать. Рандомайз только в самом начале, дальше просто рандом.

Comment: Да я знаю, как ими пользоваться. Я ж сколько лет Делфи пользовал, видел только одинаковые цепочки =) \*сейчас на старом ноуте, где D2005 есть, специально проверил. В Lazaruse поведение аналогичное.\*
Просто это звучит "любой вызов рандом будет возвращать например 4, при вызове рандомайза перед рандомами будут возвращаться разные значения" несколько двусмысленно =)

Comment: Ну знаете разные компиляторы по разному работают. Я например сейчас на PABC сваял прогу для теста и она каждый раз новые цепочки делает без рандомайза. В любом случае насколько я помню randomize позиционируется именно как инициализатор ГСЧ для random. И по стандарту его надо писать вначале программы.

Comment: Вот, хороший итог: "По стандарту его надо писать вначале программы" =)
Ну, данную особенность PABC я склонен отнести к тому, что он основан на .NET, а там дефолтный конструктор рандома без параметров использует для инициализации системное время. А конструктор должен вызываться в любом случае, вызывали мы Randomize или же не вызывали...